# How is complementation performed on cartesian products of sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

While working through Bert Mendelson's *Introduction to Topology*, I encountered a problem whose characteristics I am confused by. The problem is as follows:

Let $X ⊆ A, Y ⊆ B$. Prove that $C(X × Y) = A × C(Y) ∪ C(X) × B$.

As far as I understand, the set operation of complementation cannot be performed unless a universal set has been given. How, then, should I go about establishing an adequate proof?

The approach that I have taken involves interpreting $C(X × Y), C(Y)$, and $C(X)$ as $\{(x, y) : x ∉ X ∨ y ∉ Y\}, \{x : x ∉ Y\},$ and $\{x : x ∉ X\}$, respectively. I have included my partially complete solution below and would like to know if there exist other methods that I could have used instead, if my approach is valid, and how I should finalize my proof if so (to be more specific, how can I demonstrate that $C(X × Y) ⊆ A × C(Y) ∪ C(X) × B$ given that $x ∉ X$ and $y ∉ Y$?). Thank you in advance for your advice.

Proof: Suppose that $a ∈ C(X × Y)$. Then, a is an ordered pair $(x, y)$ such that $x ∉ X$ or $y ∉ Y$. If $x ∉ X$ and $y ∈ Y$, then $x ∈ C(X)$ and $y ∈ B$. Hence, $a = (x, y) ∈ C(X) × B ⊆ A × C(Y) ∪ C(X) × B$. If $x ∈ X$ and $y ∉ Y$, then $x ∈ A$ and $y ∈ C(Y)$. Hence, $a = (x, y) ∈ A × C(Y) ⊆ A × C(Y) ∪ C(X) × B$.

Comment: Pretty sure they mean take complements in the natural supersets. So $C(X)=A-X$, $C(Y)=B-Y$, and $C(X\times Y) = A\times B - X\times Y$.